# Panel doesn't show at startup at Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, gnome-panel

I recently installed Ubuntu 10.04 in a rather old computer, a Compaq Presario 5300. Everything went fine, the OS had no problem in the process. But when i started the computer again, the panel didn't show up. I restarted it again and again, but the problem kept on going. I've used gconftool to force it to load, but i would like to have a permanent solution to that problem.

Comment: Does `Alt + F2` bring up a `Run` dialog? If yes, please start the `Terminal` from there, and run `gnome-panel`. If the panel isn't coming up, please post the output of the command here.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your .gconf and .gconfd folders to force a complete reset all your gnome settings to the defaults. I don't know if this will help, and it will mean that you will lose any configuration changes you have made since you installed Ubuntu. For this reason, the first part of the following command only renames the folder, rather than deleting it, so you can revert the changes if necessary.

```
mv ~/.gconf ~/.gconf.old && rm -rf ~/.gconfd && gconftool-2 --shutdown && pkill gnome-panel
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem with Maverick release (10.10). After a couple of hours of google-ing *(hotkeying Firefox is never a bad ideea)*, it seemed that reinstalling the gnome panel did the trick.
Access the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and log in.

> sudo apt-get --purge remove gnome-panel*

and

> sudo apt-get install gnome-panel*

After the deed is done switch back to X console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>) and restart X server (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>BackSpace</kbd>).
Hope that proved usefull.